# after su, the script stops working

Tags: scripts, su

we are running script the the first command in it is

su (switch user)

and after that other command:

```
#!/bin/bash
su sys_osrqa
whoami
pwd
```

but when the script run, it asks for password, and after we enter the password (manually) the script stops and doesn't proceed to the following commands:

```
Password:
icsl0760>
```

ant that's it. The commands "whoami" and "pwd"are not executed.

Comment: I would not have expected anything else to happen. You need to do this like anyone else: by using `sudoers`.

Comment: could you edit your question and add what script does and that output?

Comment: `su sys_osrqa` will start an *interactive* shell for user `sys_osrqa` - control won't return to your script until that shell is exited

Answer (score 1):

su starts an interactive shell. If you want it to run explicit commands, use the -c option. In your case, I think that your script would become:

```
su -c 'whoami; pwd' sys_osrqa
```