# In a bash script, how do I change from root user to another user using su and then exit?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sudo

I've looked at [How do I run a 'sudo' command inside a script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-a-sudo-command-inside-a-script) but this seems to be a different issue.

I want to run a script to change from root to the mastodon user using `su`, run Rails commands, and then exit back to the root account and restart mastodon.

**Manually**, I can log into root via `ssh root@123.456.78.90` which gives me the `root@Mastodon:~#` shell. Then I use `sudo su - mastodon` to change to the mastodon account (I am not prompted for a password) and then `cd live`. Then I can run the Rails commands, etc., and they work, and then I can `exit` and run `systemctl restart mastodon-*`.

But my shell script to do the same thing doesn't work. The `restartall` script is

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo su - mastodon

cd live

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:generate_static_pages

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile

exit

systemctl restart mastodon-*
```

and I run it this way
`root@Mastodon:~# ./restartall`

The terminal user and path change to `mastodon@MyMastodon`, but that's all; the script fails wth:
`./restartall: line 5: cd: live: No such file or directory`

I also tried `root@Mastodon:~# sudo ./restartall`

What am I doing wrong in using `su` to change to the `mastodon` user?

Will simply using `exit` correctly take the script back to `root@Mastodon` before `systemctl restart mastodon-*` ?

Comment: Related: [after su, the script stops working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065842/after-su-the-script-stops-working)

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I tried `sudo su -c 'cd live' mastodon` and got "permission denied."

Comment: Hmm ... well `su` and `su -` are not quite the same thing; you'd need `sudo su -c 'cd live' - mastodon` or (perhaps clearer) `sudo su -l -c 'cd live' mastodon`

Comment: Another option is to use a here-document to read commands into the su shell via standard input - but that will have issues if any of the commands read stdin themselves. See for example [how to write a script that will run commands after su, without using -c](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155326/how-to-write-a-script-that-will-run-commands-after-su-without-using-c)

Comment: Ok, `sudo su - mastodon -c "cd live (bundle commands here) exit"` works and it exits correctly and runs `systemctl restart mastodon-*`, but throws "bundle: command not found" errors.

Comment: Same "bundle: command not found" with `sudo su -l -c 'cd live
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:generate_static_pages
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile
exit' mastodon`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this fails is that `sudo su - mastodon` starts a new *interactive* shell as user `mastodon`. Any commands that follow are not executed until that shell exits.

You could pass the commands to `su` via its `-c` option, as described in the previous question [after su, the script stops working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065842/after-su-the-script-stops-working), so

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo su -l mastodon -c '
  cd live
  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear
  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:generate_static_pages
  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile
'

systemctl restart mastodon-*
```

(you don't need an explicit `exit` at the end of the commands passed via `-c` since the *non*-interactive `su` shell will exit naturally when it runs out of commands to execute).

Alternatively, you could use a here-document to pass the commands to the `su` shell via standard input, as described in [how to write a script that will run commands after su, without using -c](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155348/65304) but please note the [warning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155326/how-to-write-a-script-that-will-run-commands-after-su-without-using-c#comment254048_155348) about commands that themselves read from stdin.

However you could consider avoiding `su` altogether, and writing your script so that it checks who is running it, and re-executes itself as the target user if required, like

```
#!/bin/bash

rails_user=mastodon

if [[ $EUID -ne $(id -u $rails_user) ]]; then
  echo "Switching to user '$rails_user' to perform tasks"
  exec sudo -iu "$rails_user" "$(realpath $0)"
fi

cd live
# etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! The first example works. Though I'm still getting "bundle: command not found" errors even though the script completes, exits and runs `systemctl restart mastodon-*`; that must be a different issue?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch that sounds like an issue with how `PATH` is set for user `mastodon`'s login shell - remember non-interactive bash shells don't process ~/.bashrc so you should be using ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile for things like that

Comment: Ok, I'm still learning shells. There is a .profile file, and with a file mod date in 2019, it obviously wasn't modified by the mastodon install.